# BLE : Advertising of UUID from background iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

As the iOS documentation states, when an iOS application that utilizes BLE as a peripheral moves to background mode, the local name is not advertised and all service UUIDs are placed in the overflow area. The documentation states that they can only be discovered by an iOS device.

My overall question is how exactly this happens on a lower level. Using a non-iOS bluetooth packet sniffer, I examined the advertisement data structure from my iOS peripheral app when it was in foreground and in background modes. The advertisement data structure in foreground mode looks to be what was expected, similar to other advertisement data from non-iOS devices, such as those I have coming from an Android device.

When the iOS app is background mode, this structure changes and the service UUID is not apparent. I do not see anything suggesting an “overflow” area.

How does a iOS central device discover a peripheral device that is in background mode if the UUID is not a part of the advertising data packet?

Comment: There is some information here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21284226/ios-peripheral-device-in-background My guess is that when the Apple specific manufacturer data advertisement is detected by iOS it initiates a connection to the device to retrieve the advertised service UUIDs

Comment: My experience has strictly been with central mode, but I was curious about the key [`CBCentralManagerScanOptionSolicitedServiceUUIDsKey`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Peripheral_Scanning_Options) that you specify as an option for `scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options` mentioned in the docs, and wondered if that's how you pass in the service UUIDs for discovering peripherals in that mode.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I am still unable to get this work out if the scanning device (central) is a non-iOS device. Based upon what I have read in other posts, I understand that if the central is an iOS device, didDiscoverPeripheral is called twice, with the second containing the scan response. Is there any delegate / callback that I can implement on the peripheral side where I can detect these two events?

Comment: Hello, I'm also pretty much having the same issue, where i'm using the raspberry pi to sniff the bluetooth packets. Since the app is advertising in the background raspberry couldn't recognize the which device is emitting the received ble packet. Have you got any information or luck working on this problem?

Comment: CBCentralManagerScanOptionSolicitedServiceUUIDsKey is helpful if you have a set of peripherals that you want to look for. Here you can provide the service uuid's that are might be published by the peripherals as an array and then provide that array in the scanForPeripheralsWithServices call with CBCentralManagerScanOptionSolicitedServiceUUIDsKey set to true. With this, ios informs you app whenever a peripheral discovered that is publishing anyone of the uuid's that we mentioned in the above array. Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 7):

There is a so-called overflow area according to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheralmanager/1393252-startadvertising?language=objc). More information can be found in this archive page about [Core Bluetooth concepts](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html).

I've sniffed the packets over the air. You can read the details on [github](https://github.com/crownstone/bluenet-ios-basic-localization/blob/master/BROADCASTING_AS_BEACON.md). What iOS does is broadcasting custom packages with particular bits representing UUIDs. For example UUID `3333` is represented by a bit going up in the BLE package.

> 04 3E 24 02 01 00 01 8C 91 A0 AD 8F 40 18 02 01 1A 14 FF 4C 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 D3

You see here `02` somewhere surrounded by zeros (preceding `D3` the 8-bit RSSI value).

Every UUID is one-hot encoded to a bit in this range. This will lead to collisions. You will notice that if you send `1001` by one iPhone and scan for `3333` by another iPhone you will receive the advertisements as if UUID `3333` is sent.

Note, there is a lot of nonsense written about this. It's just a regular undirected BLE packet. It's not a scan response. When running this on the background I've reliable gotten BLE packets every 0.2 seconds.

[image]

Time is on the x-axis (over a couple of days).
The interval between messages is plotted on the y-axis. You see that at times the intervals are a multiple of 0.2 seconds. However, you also see that this is shared across the three iPhones (one broadcasting `1000`, one broadcasting `FFFF`, and one broadcasting `3333` in the background). This means that this is an artifact from the laptop receiving the messages. The iPhones are probably even more robust than this. Over the entire weekend the battery drop is like `25%`, which has very likely to do with other things than the BLE broadcasting.

Comment: Important to add here, is [your blog post](https://crownstone.rocks/2018/06/27/ios-advertisements-in-the-background) @annevanRosum

from ios 12 onwards, these data are part of the SCAN_RSP packet. I can confirm that with nrf sniffer and Wireshark.
Interestingly the ADV_IND(advertisement) packet contains 8 bytes on the Data of the manufacturer specific part, which seem random and I can't find out any assosiation/reverse-engineer them.

I am also not aware, if now with Bluetooth 5.0 anything could change in future ios versions..
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/712/